# Make folder or file names shorter

Tags: 2013, save-as-template

We are trying to copy a site as a template with data/content but get the error message:

> The file path is too long: 'c***\Documentation\Shasta Development.....***.pdf'. Please make folder or file names shorter in the site and then try exporting the site again

Rather than fixing a folder and / or file name and running again to see if the error occurs, is there a way to run a console application (or some other way) to see ALL the areas we'll get the length issue.

*** Update >> We are trying this option now as of 12/23/14 12:18pm MST:

```
if (!(Get-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
    { Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell }

$siteurl = "<SharePointSiteURL>"
$site = get-spsite $siteUrl

$output=@()
foreach ($web in $site.allwebs) {
    foreach ($list in $web.lists | where {$_.basetype -eq 'DocumentLibrary'}) {
        foreach ($item in $list.items) {
            $encodedURL = $item.url -replace " ", "%20"
            $fullURL = "$($web.Url)/$($encodedURL)"
            if ($fullURL.length -gt 260) {
                $output+= New-Object psobject -Property @{
                    'File Name' = $item.name
                    'URL' = $fullURL
                    'Lenght' = $($fullURL.length)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$output | Export-Csv C:\report.csv -nti
```

Comment: You can use PowerShell to get all files in that site and update if filepath is long.

Comment: Post the script you are trying. You need to use recursion to go into different levels of the sites.

Comment: Please update the question with your script.

Comment: new script posted above

Comment: Sol Web Solutions: Can you please confirm the user who you are trying with has permissions on all the libraries. The code seems fine.

Comment: yes, full admin rights.  I'll check that sub-sites are pulled in as well.

Comment: I am using LongPathTool for this kind of errors..

Comment: Thank you...I've sent this option to our admins, but wasn't successful in having them use it